# Calculate inverse CDF from a sample of data

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, cdf

If i got a random sample data:

```
X=np.random.random(100)*100
```

and I need to get the value X_i with CDF = 34% or whatever. The only way that I am able to think right now is with inverse CDF. I thought that percentile would be equivalent but someone told me it is near but not exact.

Comment: CDF means cumulative distribution function. Thus, it is the integral of the underlying distribution function. Do you know anything about your random values' distribution? `np.random.random` has a uniform distribution and in that case the CDF and percentile matches, statistically. However for a certain sample set, especially if it is a small set, the CDF (expected values, in a sense) and the actual percentiles can vary quite a bit. Do you want the _true_ CDF from the distribution, or should you estimate it from your samples?

Answer (score 4):

This should give you the index of `X` where the cdf is 0.34:

```
X=np.random.random(100)*100
cdf_frac_to_find = 0.34
cdf = np.cumsum(X)/np.sum(X) #take the cumulative sum of x and normalize so that it's max value is 1
X_index = np.argmin(np.abs(cdf-cdf_pct_to_find))
X_index
#out: 32 -- note that this will likely change because you're generating random numbers for X.
```